# Java - while loop to check status and exit

Tags: java, while-loop

Good morning,

I have a problem using a while loop. Let me explain. I have to manage a Lamp with and IR sensor. No problem with it.
It works in this way: if a movement is noticed, the light is up, if no movement is noticed, a timeout will start and after it, the light goes down, BUT if during this timeout a new movement in noticed, the timeout must stop, "resetting" the cycle.

With no "BUT" condition, it would be easy to manage with a Tread.sleep, but I'm trying to use a while cycle to accomplish it with no result...

This is what I have, an infinite loop that checks once per second he sensor status

```
while (true) {
            try {
                if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 1) { //movement noticed
                    lampada.accendi(); //light on

                } else if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 0) { //no movement noticed
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long end = start + (timeoutSpegnimento * 1000); //10 seconds before lights shut down
                    boolean movement = false;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
                        logger.debug("Shutdown timer started");
                        if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 1) {
                            movement = true;
                            lampada.accendi(); //light up
                            logger.debug("Movement noticed - movement=" + movement);

                        } else {
                            movement = false;
                        }

                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    }
                    if (!movement) {
                        lampada.spegni(); //light off
                    }

                }
            } catch (Throwable e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                logger.error(e1);
            }
            try {

                Thread.sleep(intervallo * 1000); //do the sensor check once a second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the problem with the timeout loop `while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)`
In my idea, it should work in this way:
if `(sensore.getStatoSensore() == 0)` a while cycle timeout is called. During this while, if no new movement is noticed, the `movement` is false and so `lampada.spegni();` is called. This part works well.

But this if condition inside the while loop

```
if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 1) {
                                movement = true;
                                lampada.accendi(); //light up
                                logger.debug("Movement noticed - movement=" + movement);
```

works only the first time, than also che initial while(true) loop gets messed up, in a word, i cannot get the normal behavior anymore. I hope this explains better what i'm looking for

Comment: works "in a strange way"..  in what strange way? what happens/goes wrong? what do you expect? what do you get?

Comment: I don't see a break statement anywhere. Am I correct in guessing that the while(true) becomes an infinite loop?

Comment: the while(true) loop must be an infinite one, it continuously checks the sensor value. My problem is on the internal loop while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) because during it i must check if the sensor gets 1 to see if a new movement in noticed to stop the shutdown timeout

Comment: where is the internal loop ?!!

Comment: @Tarik he means this one:  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)

Comment: @besmart: you still haven't told us what the actual problem is

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll try to edit the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you notice movement while you're waiting for the timeout, you are not resetting the timeout, like you say in the description.

Don't combine the waiting for the first movement while the light is still out with the waiting for the timeout to expire. They are completely different things that you should not try to put in one loop, even if you manage to get it to work.

Preferably they should even be in different, well-named methods.

I've made a first stab at cleaning your code up, and also resetting the timeout if there is movement while the light is on. That should help you.

```
private boolean hasMovement() {
    return sensore.getStatoSensore() == 1;
}

private static void waitSecond() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // Wait until movement noticed
        while (!hasMovement()) {
            waitSecond();
        }
        // Movement noticed, turn light on
        lampada.accendi();

        long lastMovementTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Wait until 10 seconds from last movement
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < lastMovementTime + (timeoutSpegnimento * 1000)) {
            if (hasMovement()) {
                lastMovementTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            waitSecond();
        }

        // Turn light off
        lampada.spegni();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great and simplifies a lot my code because now I have a real timeout that updates at every new movement

Answer (score 0):

if an infinite loop is not your problem just make it without Thread.sleep:

```
long lastMovement = 0L;
while (true) {
        try {
            if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 1) { //movement noticed
                lampada.accendi(); //light on
                lastMovement = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } else if (sensore.getStatoSensore() == 0) { //no movement noticed
                long end = lastMovement + (timeoutSpegnimento * 1000); //10 seconds before lights shut down
                if (end > System.currentTimeMillis() && lastMovement > 0) {
                    lampada.spegni(); //light off
                    lastMovement = 0L;
                }

            }
        } catch (Throwable e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(e1);
        }
        try {

            Thread.sleep(intervallo * 1000); //do the sensor check once a second
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
```

- movement? Save timestamp of last movement
- no movement? Check if current time stamp > last movement timestamp: if true, lights off.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is usefull to add a method, like "lampada.isOn()", to indicate at any moment the status of the lamp (ON/OFF).
In your case, for example, it is not necessary to check Timeout when the lamp is already OFF. I think that the infinite loop comes from this permanent check